# Difference between E/SP and I/SP and other variants

Tags: pic

First post in Electronics and Robotics... I've been trying to order a DIP PIC off of Microchip (first time going directly off the website) for use with the RFM12, but I dont really know what all the variants are.

I'd like to get http://www.microchipdirect.com/ProductSearch.aspx?keywords=PIC16F873A so that it would fit on a non-solder breadboard. Most confusing is E/SP and I/SP, what's the difference? I couldnt find anything online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note [their recommendation to upgrade.](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/ProductCompare.aspx?product1=PIC16F873A&product2=PIC16F883)

Comment: I saw that, but I have some example programs to serve as a basis for this chip... as bad as this may sound, I dont want to deal with the slight changes they may have introduced in dealing with both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [their summary page](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010236), you'll see the difference is in temperature tolerance/range:

```
PIC16F873A-E/SP 28  SPDIP   -40C to +125C
PIC16F873A-I/SP 28  SPDIP   -40C to +85C
```

Comment: Is that it? I've seen the same notation elsewhere, I thought the E, I and SP might have some special meaning.

Comment: @Cenoc, *"SP"* for *SPDIP* in *"Skinny Dual In-line Package"*; *"I"* for *"industrial grade"*.

Comment: @Cenoc *"E"* is likely *"military grade"*, though it may be something else, as I usually see this go to -55C.

Comment: I think of "E" as "Extended Temperature"